# Why do I get an ImportError with PYTHONPATH set like this?

Tags: python, importerror, pythonpath

My `PYTHONPATH` contains the following path:

```
/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and I have the following relevant dir structure within site-packages:

```
graphite
  |
   --webapp
       |
        graphite
            |
             -- __init__.py
             --   .....
```

If I `(venv) cd /path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphite/webapp; ipython` then I have no problem importing with `import graphite`. Yet if the `cwd` is not that but elswhere, I am struggling to import the module. For example, in my virtualenv:

```
(venv) cd ~
(venv) ipython
```

followed by

```
from graphite.webapp import graphite
```

or

```
from .graphite.webapp import graphite
```

throw `ImportError`.

Why is this when my `PYTHONPATH` contains the above dir?

Comment: In your dir structure, you have written grahite, is that a typo in your question only or is the folder name wrong?

Comment: Do the outer graphite and webapp directories contain `__init__.py` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite clearly explained the situation (thanks for showing the tree). I assume that "grahite" was a typo. What you observe is to be expected. Your `/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphite`  directory is *not* a package, because it does not contain an `__init__.py` file.

From https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

Hence, although there is a `graphite` directory in your site-packages, it is not treated as package. You said "I am struggling to import the module", so I guess you are not 100 % familiar with the distinction between a package and a module, so you really should go over the referenced Python doc section again.

Now, if you create an `__init__.py` file in your `/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphite` directory, an `import graphite` from where -- in your words -- "the cwd is not that but elswhere" will load that "upper level" graphite package. Please note that this is *not the same* as an `import graphite` that dereferences `/path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphite/webapp/graphite`. These are two different packages, and one of them is a sub-package of the other. You need to decide which one you want to import from where, i.e. you need to get your package structure sorted out.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. I understand that `__init__.py` are needed in the dir to define a package as you say (this is why I took care to show it in the dir tree of my OP). Given that this `__init__.py` file exists at `graphite.webapp.graphite` why is doing `from graphite.webapp import graphite` a problem then? The subdir `graphite` should be a valid package, so why does this not import the package `path/to/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphite/webapp/graphite`?

Comment: Outer directories of packages also need `__init__.py`?

Comment: Python does *not* recursively scan for an `__init__.py` file and then considers any directory that has such a file anywhere below (at any level) a Python package. I think you agree that this makes sense. Otherwise your file system root would be a Python package, right? ;)

Comment: Sure, but I guess I find it hard to see the problem with just dotting down to a subdir with an `__init__.py` that is the package from somewhere on the `PYTHONPATH`, like `import path.to.package` without the need for the `path` and `to` dirs to have `__init__.py` files too. We're telling python where the package lives, so no scanning recursively is required, and I can't quite see how this type of convention would mean the whole filesystem has to end up being considered a python package, just the package dir with the `__init__.py`...

Comment: The names in import statements never purely mean/describe file or directory names. In the Python world you import a module or a package. These just happen to be organized in a directory structure. A package can also live in another package. Importing -- like in your example `path.to.package` -- implicates that there is a package called `path` with a sub-package called `to`. I think you are convinced by appreciating that the import system works primaily by names and hierarchy, not primarily by paths.